# Weird/novel Python behavior. Printing a string produces different output to saving to file

Tags: python, html, file, file-io, pycharm

I have some code. It is meant to iterate over a folder, find two points and remove everything that is NOT between these two points eg,

```
<head>
   <title>This is bad HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Remove me</h1>
  <div class="title">
    <h1> This is the good data, keep me</h1>

    <p> Keep this text </p>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h1> Remove me, I am pointless</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

should go to :

```
  <div class="title">
    <h1> This is the good data, keep me</h1>

    <p> Keep this text </p>

  </div>
```

if your two points are :

```
start=<div class="title">
end=<div class="footer">
```

The peculiar thing - when I call the Python function print to accomplish this, the code works perfectly and as expected.

When I save to file, the .html produced contains ONLY the `start` and `end` elements. I've tried printing out every value of variable and every output possible. It all makes sense when being printed to console, but messes up when saved to file.

What is going on here ?

Here is the code :

```
import os

dir = os.listdir("C:/Users/FOLDER")

files = []

for file in dir:
    if file[-5:] == '.html':
        files.insert(0, file)

for fileName in files:
    file = open("C:/Users/FOLDER/" + fileName)
    content = file.read()
    file.close()

    start = content.find('<div class="title">')
    end = content.find('<div class="footer">')

    print "Start => " + start.__str__() #This is -1 if nothing found
    print "End =>" + end.__str__()      #Same

    start = start if (start != -1) else 0 #Removing -1 if found
    end = end if (end != -1) else len(content) #Same

    print "Edited start => " + start.__str__() #Verifying -1 changed
    print "Edited end -> " + end.__str__()     #Same

    print "CONTENTS=========>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + content[start:end-1] #prints perfectly fine


    #newContent = content[start:end-1]


    file = open("C:/Users/FOLDER/" + fileName[0:-5] + "_mod" + ".html", 'w')
    file.write(content[start:end]) #Writes only the start and end nodes to file, example below
    file.close()
```

This will save to my html with _mod appended :

```
<div class="title">
<h1>Title</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
```

And NOTHING else, despite there being a large amount of text between the title and footer divs - and despite it printing correctly in the console!

Have I overlooked something here? Seems like quite a novel bug!

Comment: An aside:  `files = [fn for fn in os.listdir("C:/Users/FOLDER") if fn.endswith('.html')]`

Comment: Another aside:  `str(start)` is preferable (more pythonic) to `start.__str__()`.

Comment: This comment `#newContent = content[start:end-1]` leads me to believe you are messing with `content` somewhere but not showing us in the posted code.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I have made those two changes, thank you. Despite the commented out code, I am making no changes. WYSIWYG here - all of the code is posted up. I commented out that variable assignment whilst troubleshooting! :)

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. Are you sure you check the right file?

Comment: @hitzg I am sure and am getting this behaviour in several files....weird.

Comment: With the exact file that you posted in your question?